# Using ecrecover function - Solidity

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to verify a message, I searched on StackOverflow and I found the ecrecover function. but when I use it, it returns a different address from what I expect.

```
function verify(bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) constant returns(address) {
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(prefix, hash);
    return ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s);
}
```

signature object:

```
{
message: 'a',
messageHash: '0x34f291c0b5f0c13c8f43e9d37c04094c22234da43f4040adb36654c98235b4b3',
v: '0x1b',
r: '0x944f8187c19a711259e32dd9ab0f005c97c9e2013c735f823d3ad34c7cd5030f',
s: '0x254607e8d32e8a0436c8d678fe7d3478c8858fd903e164c51f8a8595e723b7a7',
signature: '0x944f8187c19a711259e32dd9ab0f005c97c9e2013c735f823d3ad34c7cd5030f254607e8d32e8a0436c8d678fe7d3478c8858fd903e164c51f8a8595e723b7a71b' }
```

input: (i pass it to remix-ide)

```
"0x34f291c0b5f0c13c8f43e9d37c04094c22234da43f4040adb36654c98235b4b3", 0x1b, "0x944f8187c19a711259e32dd9ab0f005c97c9e2013c735f823d3ad34c7cd5030f", "0x254607e8d32e8a0436c8d678fe7d3478c8858fd903e164c51f8a8595e723b7a7"
```

output: (wrong)

```
0x5dd277a46b3ab8ce30735d82df5e6e8312bce7ef
```

Please help me figure out the problems. many thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I don't remember. but the problem solved. Just convert string to bytes this way "0x34f291" -> "34", "f2", "91". when I passed my arguments to the function, at first, I converted it the wrong way.
anyway, thank you.